# What is the difference between dataWithBytes, dataWithBytes and initWithBytes?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am very new to iOS programming. I have a function with signature

```
(NSData*) Decrypt;
```

And in the function I have to build NSData* from char* buffer and I was trying these three functions.

```
NSData *returnData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:buflength];
NSData *returnData = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:buflength];
NSData *returnData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buflength];

return returnData;
```

Also, this code also worked.

```
return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buflength]
```

Everything except

```
NSData *returnData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buflength];
```

worked correctly. 
What is the reason ? What are the difference between them and which one is better to use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:buflength]`
and `[NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:buflength]`
are the same, the second one is just a shorthand for the first. These methods create a data object containing `buflength` bytes copied from the `buffer` bytes.

`[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buflength]` creates a data object that holds `buflength` bytes from the `buffer` bytes. The returned object takes ownership of the `buffer` pointer and frees it on deallocation. Therefore, `buffer` must point to a memory block allocated with `malloc`.